# Border-radius bleeding

Tags: css, css-sprites

I want to give border-radius to a `<nav>` in which all the `<a>` have an image has background, but the image keeps going outside the border-radius. Why is that?

Comment: which browser? works fine for me in firefox

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To fix this in all browsers you should use:

```
-moz-background-clip: padding; 
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

I found the answer [here](http://css3please.com/)

Comment: Thanx! I had to figure out why this not always worked: background-clip must be **AFTER** *border, border-radius, background* and all other proprieties that could matter (FireFox 49.0.2 under Linux).

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

To fix this in Webkit.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with a `bootstrap panel` border or background bleeding to a `HTML` header `<h> element` above the `bootstrap panel`. The `<h>` element has `class="page-header"` and is contained in a `div` element with `class="col-lg-12"`.  The answers here and in other places didn't work for me.

What worked was adding this to the `panel`s CSS class:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

I got the direction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401442/border-radius-background-bleed) from Carol's answer.

Edit:

This caused another problem for me. I had Dropdown controls in the panel and the `overflow:hidden;` caused the dropdowns to be cut off and not displayed fully.

The dropdowns are contained in `div` elements with Bootstrap `col-lg` classes. I added `style="position: inherit"` to those `div` elements containing the dropdowns and that solved the problem.

The solution to that problem I found [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T269461/aspxroundpanel-overlays-drop-down-windows-of-aspxcombobox-and-aspxdateedit-if-the).

**Additional Option:**

I added 3 or 4 `<br/>` elements before the `div` tag that was bleeding and that solved the bleeding problem without any bad side effects.