# Border-radius doesn't affect inner elements

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I have a layout where the all of the page content is in a box with rounded corners. This includes the title of the page, etc. I have a `div` element that contains my header content, a `div` that contains the main content of the page, and a `div` that contains the footer. My problem is this: Since the border of my "header" `div` is not rounded, the large "container" `div` seems to not be rounded at the top. I have investigated, and shown that this is simply the "header" `div` superimposing itself over the "container" `div`. I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/V98h7/.

I have tried rounding the border of the "header" `div` to the same extent, but this creates a small defect on the border (it gains a border of its own, of the "header" `div`'s background color).
Out of desperation, I also tried setting the z-index of the container to a large number. THat did not do anything.

I feel that there should be a simple solution to this problem. I do not want a javascript fix. I would prefer CSS, but LESS is ok too.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/V98h7/2/

Add -

```
#outer {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

and it will work.

More information on the [`overflow` property can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
#outer { overflow: hidden; }
```

or this:

```
#inner1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Or you maybe can try this:

```
#outer div:first {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

(Note: I haven't tested the last option above).

Answer (score 0):

here is the update jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V98h7/1/

To just round border corners `border-radius` can take 4 values `TOP-LEFT RADIUS` `TOP-RIGHT RADIUS` `BOTTOM-RIGHT RADIUS` `BOTTOM-LEFT-RADIUS`

so `border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;` will round your inner div from top. Remember to use the same radius value as that of the parent div, else you will see some extra border.

Comment: As i said in my post, this causes glitches in some browsers.

Comment: Can u tell which browsers, would help me testing as well. Am using the same code numerous places in my projects.

Comment: In Chrome i see this error a lot. It is very slight, but present.

Answer (score 0):

Border fix for css border-radius background color bleed and inner elements breaking border radius. This might help with the weird border glitches.

```
/* useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border: */
-moz-background-clip: padding; 
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

This reference was found here http://css3please.com/
by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052769/9071880

Answer (score -2):

Try giving the container div a slightly larger border radius (on the top two corners) than the header div.