# Change background color under border-radius of specific element

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I'm adding a border radius to the bottom of my sections. The background color of my body is black. I'm trying to have the color under each border-radius match the background-color of the next section. Not the background color of the body. Didn't know how to word question to find on google, sorry in advanced if question has already been asked.

[Border Radius Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3dHs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a before pseudo-element and z-index -1, it's kinda tricky:

```css
section {
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

section:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px; /* border radius size * -1 */
  left: 0;
  height: 40px; /* border radius size */
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: magenta;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: cyan;
}

section:nth-child(odd):after {
  background-color: magenta;
}

section:nth-child(even):after {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-river-iwxz4c?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I was thinking something like this would be the next best solution I just wanted to know for sure or if there was something a bit more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry but it's hard to tell anything without seeing the coding. Please at least share code for solution. Thanks

Comment: Simple questions don't require code. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652641/border-radius-bleeding

Answer (score 0):

Share with us what you have tried (the original code) so we can be more clear about the problem and can tell you any fix to the problem.

Comment: Simple questions don't require code. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652641/border-radius-bleeding