# Creating a circular meter, background color is creating problems

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a circular meter which will update according to value. the problem is there is a red border out of out circle... is there a good way to remove that...
 This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/aAeSk/)

This is HTML Code:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left-cov"></div>
    <div class="right-cov"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p class="fy-rate">1.5</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

following is CSS code for this:

```css
* {
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.outer {
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.inner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}
.left-cov {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:grey
}
.right-cov {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.fy-rate {
    font-size:52px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:45px;
}
```

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks try the fiddle you can find what you need :)

Comment: Hi, look for **border-radius background bleed** over the net for your answer : https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=border-radius+bleed There are some Stackoverflow questions about this situation : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=border-radius+bleed

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an anti-aliasing problem.

The only thing you can do is either adding a box-shadow for slight improvement:

```
.left-cov {
  ...
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 gray;
}
```

(JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aAeSk/2/)

or do it in a HTML5 canvas with more design control possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasted from this answer : [Border Radius = Background Bleed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401442/border-radius-background-bleed) by user [mingos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244727/mingos), answered Dec 9 '10 at 18:10 :

> It's not what you're waiting for, I know, but I have to say this:
>   **use an image**. This is not only due to the possibility to eliminate the bleed on all browsers. Your bleed problem on Firefox is nothing
>   compared to how Chrome mercilessly slaughters the look of your
>   buttons... Check it and start crying :(.-moz-background-clip: padding; [...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401442/border-radius-background-bleed)